# Explaining regression coefficients

Tags: least-squares, regression-coefficients

It may be a rather silly question that a first-year econometrics student could answer, but I got my brain stuck with it.

Assume that I run a regression of `log(wages)` on education, i.e. `lm(lwage) ~ education)`, where education is a dummy variable with "0" representing High School, and "1" standing for the Bachelor's degree.

In the regression with education dummy alone, the Bachelor's degree coefficient is estimated to be 0.65; this can be interpreted that students with the BS degree will have on average `exp(0.65)-1= 0.9155 = 92%` higher wages than high-school graduates.

Now, assume I introduce years of work experience as another (continuous) variable into the regression. Then the coefficient on Bachelor's dummy drops to 0.4 or `exp(0.4)-1= 0.491 = 49%`.

Now, can I say that work experience variable is responsible for explaining the variation in wages for the amount by which education coefficient has changed? That is, is it safe to state that an average individual will be making 49% higher average wage if he has a BS degree, while another extra (92%-49%)= 43% of his higher wage is attributed to his work experience?

Or it is not possible to directly interpret regression coefficients like this, because the explained sum of squares (SSE) will be different between two models, etc?

Comment: What is the value of the coefficient related to work experience? This should tell you the effect of work experience, not the dummy.

Comment: Coefficient on work experience variable shows the average return to each additional year of experience, and will be different for each person in my sample. What I need is to see by how much average value (in terms of wages) of the formal degree reduces when another explanatory variable is introduced.

Comment: There is something going wrong there. I don't have the time right now to write out an explanation, but I'll do that tomorrow if nobody has done it before me then.

Comment: If you are getting different estimators for the effect of experience for each person, you are doing something weird with the model specification. Do you have the code of your analysis?